# Is there a material TimerPicker widget in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, timepicker, cupertinopicker

I want to implement a time picker widget to allow users to record duration (hours and minutes) and I also want to show differently depending on the device platform (iOS or Android).

For iOS, I can use `CupertinoTimerPicker` and `CupertinoActionSheet` widgets, which are originally included in Flutter. (like this: [CupertinoTimerPicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJw2K.png))  Users can swipe the picker wheel to select the duration.
However, I can't find the material widget that corresponds to them (like this: [time picker for Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFAgN.png)).

Is there a material TimerPicker widget in Flutter, or do I have to use a external package?

Comment: You can see here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showTimePicker.html

Comment: whats wrong with `CupertinoTimerPicker`?

Comment: @Junaid Khalid: It's not compatible with Material (for Android, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Work is in progress, see in github..
[https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91605](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WBWZ.png)

Comment: The question was about to pick Duration, not to pick TimeOfDay